# Convert DateTime to Varchar

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on a query in Sql Server 2008 where I'm migrating the date to a different table.

The source table has a column with DateTime and the destination column has varchar column. I need to convert a DateTime values into varchar.

Source Column has DateTime: `2007-02-13 00:00:00.000`

Destination Column has Varchar: `mm/dd` format

Comment: If you're dealing with dates, why treat them as anything *other* than datetime values, especially down in the database? The vast majority of problems people encounter dealing with datetime values is when they've converted them to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me preface with:

**THIS IS A TERRIBLE IDEA**

If your data represents a date, it needs to be a date datatype!

If you insist on going forward, though, you can do something along the lines of:

`SELECT CAST(MONTH(Datefield) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DAY(Datefield) as varchar)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (T-SQL) function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

EDIT

`SELECT CAST(DATEPART(MM, YourDateTimeField) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, YourDateTimeField) AS VARCHAR(2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YourDate,101) NewDate
FROM YourTable
```